# Java Reading String with multiple line

Tags: java, string

I have a string with multiple line, I want to display them individually example when I only want to display the first inline it will show only 'apple'

```
Example display line 1 = orange
```

What i haven done is as follows, it can display all but unable to select which fruit position to display

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {


        String fruit = "apple" + "\n" + "orange"+"\n"+"pear";

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(fruit));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

output: 
apple
orange
pear
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) instead, for example...

```
String fruit = "apple" + "\n" + "orange"+"\n"+"pear";
String[] basket = fruit.split("\n");
```

This will allow you to access each element individually by index

Comment: I have done the same thing before which is reading from file, but now i try to read from a string instead

Comment: @user2822351 Okay, and the difference being?

Comment: haha I dont know as it didnt show Stringreader can use split, it wasnt stated in the book

Comment: `split` can be used with any `String`, it's a method of the `String` class